# ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xdb in position 942: ordinal not in range(128) sql query

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

As I use some Arabic script in my query and Python can't decode Arabic characters to ASCII and Python 2 uses bytestrings (ASCII) strings by default, which support only Latin characters. Python 3 uses Unicode strings by default.

query :

```
query = """SELECT * FROM (
               SELECT p.ID AS 'persons_ID', 
                 p.FirstName AS 'persons_FirstName', 
                 p.LastName AS 'persons_LastName',
                 p.NationalCode AS 'persons_NationalCode', 
                 p.CityID AS 'persons_CityID', 
                 p.Mobile AS 'persons_Mobile',
                 p.Address AS 'persons_Address', 
                 cities_1.ID AS 'cities_1_ID', 
                 cities_1.Name AS 'cities_1_Name',
                 cities_1.ParentID AS 'cities_1_ParentID', 
                 cities_2.ID AS 'cities_2_ID', 
                 cities_2.Name AS 'cities_2_Name',
                 cities_2.ParentID AS 'cities_2_ParentID' , 
                 cast(@row := @row + 1 as unsigned) as 'persons_row_number'                                                                              
               FROM Persons p 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN cities AS cities_2 
               ON cities_2.ID = p.CityID 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN cities AS cities_1 
               ON cities_1.ID = cities_2.ParentID , (
                 select @row := 0) as init WHERE 1=1
                 AND p.FirstName LIKE N'{}%'""".format('رامین')
```

i use format('رامین') i get error UnicodeEncodeError from MysqlDB,

Comment: Did you set an encoding?  (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

Comment: To handle Arabic (or any other non-Latin) characters you have to use unicode in Python

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this.  However, if I copy/paste your code into a python2.7 script, I get a `SyntaxError`.  I need to set the encoding before I can even import the module.  Once I do that, the formatting _seems_ to work just fine -- Which would imply that the error is further on (in code you haven't shown us) since you're claiming that you see a `UnicodeEncodeError`...  Maybe you aren't using a string literal for `'رامین'`?

Comment: i use query with SQLAlchemy , other sample :
`code`
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import sqlparse


name = u"رامین"

sql = 'select * from "someschema"."mytable" where id="%s"' % name
parsed = sqlparse.parse(sql)
print parsed[0]